# SSH Unreachable after large SCP transfer

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, file-transfer, scp

Recently built a new i9 server; it is running ubuntu 14.

This has happened 4 times in the last 2 months, and today it may have caused a loss of a day's worth of experimental data.

Here is what happened:

- Server has been running fine for a few weeks
- 2 or 3 users on it at a time during peak hours
- Today I initiate an SCP transfer (26MB) from the server to a remote cluster in
  a different country (Server: Canada, cluster: Germany)
- SCP reaches 16% and all SSH communication stops
- My SSH session is unresponsive, unable to open new sessions; other users on the server see the same symptoms (unresponsive sessions, unable to open new ones)
- The file is available on the cluster, however it is incomplete / corrupted

Pinging the server yields: "Destination Host Unreachable"

To get the server running again, we have to restart the physical machine.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how to fix it? This has happened 4 times since building the new server and every time it has occurred when transferring files 20-30MB from the server to the cluster. Although it does not happen every time we transfer these files, it happens 5% of the time.

EDIT: Here are the logs around the time of the SSH server becoming unavailable (from var/log/syslog):

```
Sep 26 09:17:01 snail CRON[34116]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report/etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 26 10:17:01 snail CRON[34137]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Sep 26      12:36:14 snail rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="763" x-info="http:/     /www.rsyslog.com"] start
Sep 26 12:36:14 snail rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Sep 26 12:36:14 snail rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

The server became unresponsive arouns 11:30 and I restarted it (physically) at 12:36; so the logs don't tell us anything about what happened at 11:30

** 'snail' is the name of the server

Comment: 20MB is very small by todays' standards. Have you checked if larger files make the failure happen consistently?What do you see in the system logs when the problem occurs (`/var/log/syslog`).

Comment: The largest file I currently have on the server is 106MB; I trasfered it to the German server 10 times with no issues.

As for the logs I'll add then to my question

Comment: Looks like `sshd` crashed pretty hard, for whatever reason. The NUL characters in the syslog are not what should happen, either, so possibly something else crashed, too. Could be a corrupted binary, bad RAM, or lots of other reasons. Things to try: Get a second channel to the server (e.g. a second `sshd` with another port), keep a session on this channel open, see if you can get a `dmesg` when the next crash happens. Also try to restart the first `sshd`.